# Different vibration sounds for different contacts

Tags: notifications, vibration

I would like to have different notification "vibrations" based on who messages me. Ideally, this would be done on any of the main messaging apps (Facebook Messenger, WhatsApp, Snapchat, Signal, etc.)

Currently, Facebook Messenger does have a different vibration sound than WhatsApp (it has a lighter vibration), so I know that I am getting a notification from Facebook Messenger rather than WhatsApp. That being said, I don't know who is messaging me.

The Nothing Phone (1) aims to solve this problem by having a different array of light based on the notification, but can the same be implemented on any Android phone via vibrations (which has more functionality too since you can use it while in your pocket).

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S20 5g unlocked without root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BuzzKill app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samruston.buzzkill&hl=en_AU&gl=US) will give custom vibrations for specific notifications or contacts.

It also has other powerful features such as

- Cooldown - Only get buzzed once even if there are multiple notifications in a short space of time
- Batch - Save notifications until a certain time.

[Is there any free alternative Of buzzkill ? : androidapps](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/pdo7qn/is_there_any_free_alternative_of_buzzkill/)

> - [Filterbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catchingnow.np)
> - [Spren](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spren.android)
> - [Nap](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.leao.nap)